# Getting error Argument of type is not 'X' is not assignable to parameter of type 'X' in the NextApiResponse in NextJS

Tags: typescript, next.js

I have the following code

```
type Data = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  price: number;
};

const FetchMeals = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse<Data>) => {
  const response = await fetch(
    "https://url.com/Meals.json"
  );

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error("Something went wrong");
  }

  const responseData = await response.json();

  const loadedMeals:Data[] = [];

  for (const key in responseData) {
    loadedMeals.push({
      id: key,
      name: responseData[key].name,
      description: responseData[key].description,
      price: responseData[key].price,
    });
  }

  res.status(200).json({ loadedMeals });
  
};

export default FetchMeals;
```

I have defined the type of body of the response as the type above, and defined the type with `< >` brackets next to `NextApiResponse`. The type of the body should be an array of Data. I've got two questions here. If I define my array with the type `Data` like `const loadedMeals:Data[] = [];` at the id in the code below

```
for (const key in responseData) {
    loadedMeals.push({
        id: key,
        name: responseData[key].name,
        description: responseData[key].description,
        price: responseData[key].price,
    });
}
```

I'm getting an error "string type is not assignable to type number".

**Question 1)** How come the type of id in the for loop becomes string?

At loadedMeals in `res.status(200).json({ loadedMeals });` it's showing this error

> Argument of type '{ loadedMeals: Data[]; }' is not assignable to
> parameter of type 'Data'.   Object literal may only specify known
> properties, and 'loadedMeals' does not exist in type 'Data'.

**Question 2)** Why is it showing this error?

When I do a postman GET request it's returning the correct array with the values but IDE shows this error. Is it just something to do with IDE or is my TypeScript code wrong that I should be adding something to my code. This is Next.js API routing and the IDE I'm using is VSCode.

I did look up answers but couldn't understand what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: If you log `responseData` to the console, what's the output?

Comment: I'm getting the expected result in my nodejs terminal. on the browser console its showing an error handling response. Its there even if I don't console.log

Comment: That's fine, I just want to see the format of the response. What does it look like?

Comment: oh yeah it is in json format. works fine if i enter the url 'http://localhost:3000/api/FetchMeals' in postman with a get request. it is returning in json format

Comment: {
  m1: {
    description: 'Finest fish and veggies',
    name: 'Sushi',
    price: 22.99
  },
  m2: {
    description: 'A german specialty!',
    name: 'Schnitzel',
    price: 16.5
  },
  m3: {
    description: 'American, raw, meaty',
    name: 'Barbecue Burger',
    price: 12.99
  },
  m4: {
    description: 'Healthy...and green...',
    name: 'Green Bowl',
    price: 18.99
  }
}
I'm fetching this from firebase. And it returns this. when console.log responseData

Comment: when console.log loadedMeals
[
  {
    id: 'm1',
    name: 'Sushi',
    description: 'Finest fish and veggies',
    price: 22.99
  },
  {
    id: 'm2',
    name: 'Schnitzel',
    description: 'A german specialty!',
    price: 16.5
  },
  {
    id: 'm3',
    name: 'Barbecue Burger',
    description: 'American, raw, meaty',
    price: 12.99
  },
  {
    id: 'm4',
    name: 'Green Bowl',
    description: 'Healthy...and green...',
    price: 18.99
  }
]

Comment: You should type the `res` object as `res: NextApiResponse<{ loadedMeals: Data[] }>` to match what you're returning in the response.

Comment: Thanks. legend. This works. So we are passing res as a parameter of Type NextApiResponse with loadedMeals:Data[] as object. Am I correct. If possible can u explain this a bit @juliomalves

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The generic type passed to `NextApiResponse` will determine the type of the data returned by `res.json()`.

In your case, you're returning `{ loadedMeals }` in the response, where `loadedMeals` is an array of `Data` objects. This means the returned object type corresponds to `{ loadedMeals: Data[] }`.

You should type the generic type passed to `NextApiResponse` accordingly to match that response.

```js
const FetchMeals = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse<{ loadedMeals: Data[] }>) => {
    // existing code
    
    res.status(200).json({ loadedMeals }); // The type of `{ loadedMeals }` is `{ loadedMeals: Data[] }`
}
```